# Magento 1.9 Email Problem

Tags: product, price, order-email

I am working on a website , I have installed porto 2.2.0 there are 2 issues I was unable to solve,

1) Email on order did not work.

2) I want to remove `.00` from price.

I have tried many articles but all in vain.

Answer (score 1):

If you have properly configured Magento 2 mailing systems, you may need to check below point:

- Got to Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System

Under Mail Sending Settings make sure Disable Email Communications is set to No. Also verify your Host and Port fields if you are using any external mailing server.

- Got to Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails

Under General Settings tab, choose Asynchronous sending to Disable

Under Order tab Enabled to Yes

Now clear/refresh your cache.

Hope this helps you. This solution is tested with Magento 2

Comment: I am using magento 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Try this !!

1) First go to `System > Configuration > Sales Emails` and make sure that Enabled is set to Yes.

After that look in `core_email_queue` table. If there are entries in the table and customers/admin are not getting any emails it means cron job is not running.

More details [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-responsive-email#cron).

2) You could take a look at [here](https://marketplace.magento.com/etws-et-currencymanager.html) I have never used it but I can see you can manage the decimal places and more

"Who needs cents anyway? You can display price without zero cents. Example: display 49 instead of 49.00, but leave 49.99 unchanged."

Plus it free :-)

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html This link is not working its forwarded to magento marketplace.
Also i am seeing mail queuoe in core_email_queue but did not know what to do next.

Comment: Updated Answer !!